# compiling OpenGL program GL/glew.h missing

Tags: linux, opengl, glew

I installed OpenGL onto my computer running Linux Mint following the instructions on [this tutorial](http://anytimeir.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/installing-opengl-development-environment-in-ubuntu/). I am trying to compile a program that uses OpenGL, but I'm getting a compile error: `fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory`. I check the /usr/include/GL folder, and glew.h is indeed missing. I don't know why it's missing, because I did the command `sudo apt-get install libglew1.5` and it gives the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglew1.5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 465 not upgraded.
```

Why is the glew.h file missing?

Comment: FYI: GLEW 1.5 [is *ancient*; it's from 2007](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). You shouldn't use it for anything, and if a tutorial is telling you to do so, you should use another tutorial.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hmm...well this is the tutorial given to me by my professor. What alternatives are there?

Comment: @NicolBolas I tried doing apt-get install for 1.9, and it said it couldn't find it. I kept trying for every newer version and kept getting the same error until 1.6. And even after installing 1.6, I'm still having the same problem--glew.h is still missing.

Comment: You could probably use [`GLee`](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) instead, it does the same stuff as GLEW but easier to use.  Just one header and one C file to add to your project.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`libglew` is just the library, but not the development files (headers). You need to install those separately. The package name on Debian based systems is `libglew-dev`
and for fedora(and possibly its derivatives)  it is `glew-devel`

Comment: # Perfect, command works for Fedora 29 # sudo dnf install glew-devel

Comment: 9 years later, this saved me from giving up!  I love S.O. lol

Answer (score 50):

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev
```